# Added Admob to my existing project now it's not running

Tags: android, compiler-errors, admob

I updated to 1.4 RC 1 and wanted to add adMob to existing project now android studio not compiling project. I tried to return everything back but doesn't matter not running project. Always giving error about Theme. I deleted all written codes from Manifest, MainActivity, main_activity layout, String, build.gradle which belongs to adMob. Noway. I read many threads but nothing written about it.please i can't solve myself, need help. thanks.
`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
}`

[code]Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
G:\AndroidStudioProjects\UzbekKoreanDictionary\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
Error:(28, 67) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'background'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
Error:(27, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
Error:(28, 67) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'background'.
Error:(27, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
Error:(28, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarItemBackground'.
Error:(27, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\android-sdk-07_08_14\android-sdk-15.07.13\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1.497 secs
>   Information:14 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console
>   [/code]

Answer (score 1):

Your error log shows you are missing appcompat support library in your gradle file. You can add to the dependencies at app/build.gradle the following line:

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

Comment: thanks brother for answer, but it didn't help me, is there other way?

Comment: Still the same error? Can you post the contents of your build.gradle file?

Comment: Thanks brother after adding  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1' 80% of error disappeared. Errors with Theme there is no longer. Now another error is coming, please advice brother

Comment: Use compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'. I think you can also use version 22, like compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "namangan.grandmir.uz.uzbekkoreandictionary"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 17
        versionName "2.17.2"

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      '      proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```